# Android how to sort and unsorted in same button click event

Tags: android, android-listview

how can sort and unsorted in list view, when ever i click on list view header i want to sort list of objects after next click i want to unsorted the items, for binding objects to list view i used Adapter, for sorting i used Collection.Sort(list) and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag variable and toggle it on each click e.g. true means ascending and false means descending.

Comment: can u send me one sample for that flags

Comment: Have you implemented the creation of listview?

Comment: ya, see my sample code  LitemItemAdapter mcqListAdapter = new LitemItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row,books);
        bookListView.setAdapter(mcqListAdapter);
        
        bookListView.setClickable(true);
        btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.item2);
       
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
     Arrays.sort(books);
     bookListView.invalidateViews();
    
   }
  });   In Button click event i sort list view but in same event i want to unsort those items

Answer (score 0):

You have to add button.setOnClickListener(this); 
and on onClick(View v) method you have to write logic for sorting.
But for unsorting logic you have to store the list in temp list before applying sorting and when you want to unsort the list just copy temp lsit to your main list.